# Current request spikes every 7 minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request, iis-7.5

On our webhomes on a iis 7.5 webserver there is an increase in active request in a cycle of 7 minutes. 5 minutes everything is quite normal then comes an increase in active request for 2 minutes.

While active requests increases, ntoskrnl.exe also has an increase in cpu load.

Are there anybody who can give me any clues to what I shall look for?

[image: Active requests]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things that we did notice, was that the Garbage Collector was going nuts every 5 minuttes.

After a server restart everything is fine again.